# Javascript's Date.getTimezoneOffset returns 0 when running on remote server

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, remote-server, timezone-offset

I'm in Philippines and running this line of code in localserver/localhost returns a timezone offset correctly.

```
console.log(new Date().getTimezoneOffset());
// output: -480
```

But when I run this code in remote server it outputs `0`.

My localserver setup:
Mac os, node.js, and mongodb

Our remote sever setup:
ec2 instance in Amazon web services (AWS), running ubuntu os, node.js and mongodb.

Does anyone here know how to get the timezone offset when running from remote server?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the correct timezone on your server. On an Ubuntu server you can input the following command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

Choose the correct timezone for you and then you'll get the correct timezone when using: `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()`

---

In case you need to handle multiple timezones, I recommend using [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) to do it easily.

```
const moment = require('moment');
const losAngeles = moment().tz('America/Los_Angeles');
console.log(losAngeles.format());

const manila = moment().tz('Asia/Manila');
console.log(manila.format());
```

Comment: This system will be used in other country also which has different timezone. Is it okay to set timezone in this server?

Comment: Yes, I need to handle multiple timezone. How can i set?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your server timezone:

```
timedatectl
```

I guess it may be "Etc/UTC (UTC, +0000)". If so, that means your server is currently set to UTC. This isn't physical place where your server is located. We can set our computer to any timezone.

However, for the server, I recommend to keep the timezone as UTC. So we can do any calculations relating to date/time based on a standard unit. We should store the date time values in the database as UTC time.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is getting timezone offset from the back-end. So I change my codes and get the timezone offset from the front-end because web browser can return timezone offset from any location access.